# remove all leading and trailing whitespace from both file and directory names recursively

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, zsh

I have directory structure like the following:

```
.
├── ParentDirectory
│   ├── ChildDirectory1
│   │   ├── 01-File.txt
│   │   ├── 02-File.txt
│   │   ├──      03-File.adoc
│   │   ├──    04-File.md
│   │   └──     05-File.txt
│   ├──     ChildDirectory2
│   │   ├── 01-File.txt
│   │   ├── 02-File.txt
│   │   ├──    03-File.adoc
│   │   ├── 04-File.txt
│   │   ├── 05-File.txt
│   │   └──     06-File.md
│   ├── ChildDirectory3
│   │   ├──     01-File.txt
│   │   ├── 02-File.txt
│   │   ├── 03-File.adoc
│   │   ├── 04-File.md
│   │   ├──    05-File.md
│   │   └── 06-File.txt
```

You may have noticed that some file and directory has leading whitespace. What you may not have noticed is some file and directory has trailing whitespace as well.

For trailing whitespace I tried:

```
% find . -exec rename 's/ *$//' {} +
```

I have to run this command multiple times. On first run it rename parent directory. On second run it rename the child. My directory structure actually goes much deeper. So, running a command multiple times is not a good solution.

For leading whitespace `find . -exec rename 's/^ *//' {} +` does not work at all.

How can I remove all leading and trailing whitespace from both file and directory names recursively?

Comment: Did you try depth-first search? You can do that by supplying the -depth flag to find.

Comment: Yes now `find . -depth -exec rename 's/^ *//' {} +` works. Still `find . -depth -exec rename 's/^ *//' {} +` not working.

Comment: @blueray You just said that a command was and was not working, at the same time.

Comment: Also, at no point do you actually say what "not working" means. Does it produce errors? What are those errors? Does it rename files in the wrong manner? Not at all?  Does your filenames contain tab characters?

Comment: @Kusalananda the command runs without any error. But it does not remove the leading whitespace.

Comment: @blueray Then you probably have other whitespace characters than only space at the start of names.

Comment: I also tried `find . -depth -name "* *" -execdir rename 's/^ *//' "{}" \;` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40154622/1772898 . However, it does not matter anymore. The accepted solution actually solves all my rename issues universally. I just add/remove/modify the `$base`. It just took a little time to understand what it is actually doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '(**/)(*)' '$1${${2##[[:space:]]#}%%[[:space:]]#}'
```

(remove `-n` (dry-run) if happy).

Add a `(#qD)` at the end of the pattern, if you also want to process hidden files and files in hidden directories.

With `rename`, that would be something like:

```
find . -depth ! -name . -exec rename -n '
  my ($dir, $base) = m{(.*)/(.*)}s;
  $base =~ s/^\s*//;
  $base =~ s/\s*$//;
  $_ = "$dir/$base";' {} +
```

Though note that `\s` (contrary to zsh's `[[:space:]]`) only matches on ASCII whitespace, not the other whitespace characters in your locale. `rename` also doesn't have any of `zmv`'s safeguards to check for conflicts before starting the renaming.

In any case, note that on several systems, including GNU ones, the non-breaking-space character (U+00A0) is not considered whitespace on the ground that it's not meant to delimit words, so it won't be removed, even with the `zmv`  approach. If you have such characters, you could strip them with:

```
zmv -n '(**/)(*)' $'$1${${2##[[:space:]\ua0]#}%%[[:space:]\ua0]#}'
```

Comment: By the way, what does `my ($dir, $base) = m{(.*)/(.*)}s;` do?

Comment: @blueray, it splits the path into directory (`$dir`) and filename (`$base`) parts to get the equivalent of `$1` and `$2` in `zmv`.

Comment: Thank you very much.